# Fitting splines using mgcv

Tags: r, regression, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

I have the following example, where I fit a spline to a simple data set using the `mgcv`-package in `R` and plot it afterwards:

```
dev.off()

dfOne <- data.frame(1*(1:20),
                    c(1,6,2,8,7,4,9,8,5,4, c(1,6,2,8,7,4,3,8,5,4)/2),
                    3*(1:20))
colnames(dfOne)<-c("one", "two", "three")



fml <- as.formula(three ~ s(one, by=two, k=8,pc=10) )
GAM1 <- mgcv::gam(formula = fml, data = dfOne)


require(ggplot2)
data_plot<-qplot(dfOne$one, dfOne$two,colour="blue") +
  geom_line(colour="red",aes(y=fitted(GAM1))) +
  theme_bw()
print(data_plot)
```

Here is a plot of the spline to `dfOne$one, dfOne$three` and the data points `dfOne$one, dfOne$two`:

[image]

1. Note how I fit the spline to `dfOne$three` using `dfOne$two`. In other words, I expect the spline to follow `dfOne$three` and the trend of `dfOne$two`. Indeed it follows the linear increase of `dfOne$three`. However, look at the horizontal axis between values 1-5. There the spline is anti-correlated with `dfOne$two`. Why is that?
2. As a test I used `k=8` to only use 8 knots. But as far as I can count, there are 18 knots/bends in the spline. Why is that?
3. I also use `pc=10` to force the spline to pass through zero at 10. But this doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: 1. I find your plot strange. Consider plotting `ggplot(dfOne, aes(x = one, y = three)) +
  geom_point(colour="blue") +
  geom_line(colour="red",aes(y=fitted(GAM1))) +
  theme_bw()` as well as `ggplot(dfOne, aes(x = two, y = three)) +
  geom_point(colour="blue") +
  geom_line(colour="red",aes(y=fitted(GAM1))) +
  theme_bw()`.

Comment: 2. You have not understood what a knot is. Reread the relevant chapter in your textbook. You can't see the knots in this plot. 3. `plot(GAM1)` might be elucidating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_bw())
library("mgcv")

df <- data.frame(one   = 1*(1:20),
                 two   = c(1,6,2,8,7,4,9,8,5,4, c(1,6,2,8,7,4,3,8,5,4)/2),
                 three = 3*(1:20))
m <- gam(three ~ s(one, by=two, k = 8, pc=10), data = dfOne)
```

#### Q1

What your model is fitting is a *centred* smooth effect of `one` *multiplied* by `two`. The spline itself is quite smooth:

[image]

Next note that the estimates of the spline for the first `n` elements are all negative and quite similar in magnitude, esp the first few where you see the anticorrelated behaviour:

```
> head(fitted(m))
[1] 25.936853  4.209230 23.373273  5.188732 12.415398 22.525351
> head(predict(m, type = "terms")[,1])
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
 -5.118848 -26.846471  -7.682427 -25.866969 -18.640302  -8.530349
```

What you see here is the relatively similar contribution from the smooth being multiplied by the quite different value of `two` for these first two elements. As the spline effects are negative, the resulting contribution is somewhat negative for the first value and much more strongly negative for the second value, and so on.

This is all due to the model you specified; estimate a spline ,evaluate the spline at the *i*th location and multiply that effect by the *i*th row of the numeric `by` variable.

#### Q2

Knots are not inflexions of the resulting fitted values. In fact, there are as many knots as data points as you used a thin plate spline here. There `k` represents the dimension of the basis expansion (in this the dimension is 7 because you loose 1 due to the centring constraints imposed on the spline), and **mgcv** employs a neat trick to select 7 basis functions from the `n` basis functions in a traditional thin plate spline basis. (The basis functions are subject to an eigen decomposition and the eigenvectors associated with `k-1` largest eigenvalues are used as a new basis. This concentrates most of the information in the full thin plate spline basis into a smaller set of orthogonal basis functions for model fitting.)

The estimated coefficients clearly indicate that only 7 basis functions were used in the model:

```
> coef(m)
 (Intercept) s(one):two.1 s(one):two.2 s(one):two.3 s(one):two.4 s(one):two.5 
 31.05570043   0.70385580  -0.65193244  -0.01680226  -0.21851339   0.14293203 
s(one):two.6 s(one):two.7 
 -0.52163338   5.27573517
```

#### Q3

As the plot of the spline shows, the spline does pass through `x = 10` as you requested.

You are confusing the fitted values of the **model** with the estimated spline.